# Angular validation logic with async calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, synchronization

I'm using Angular 1 and having to implement some validation logic in a controller as follow:

```
$scope.onValidate = function(){
    var orderId = $resource("/getorderId");
    if (!orderId){
        return false;
    }

    var isValidAddress = $resource("/checkAddress")
    if (!isValidAddress){
        return false;
    }

    // some other checking 

    return true;
}
```

But as we know $resource is async and will return immediately. My question is what should be the right approach in Angular 1 to perform such sequential checking which needs to get result from server side and should wait until all conditions are checked before return.

Comment: When do you want this server-side validation to happen? After the user click a submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood is, you wanted to put validation on change of input value, You need to use `$asyncValidator` over input field `ngModel`.

```
ngModel.$asyncValidators.myValidation = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    var value = modelValue || viewValue;
    var orderPromise = $resource("/getorderId").then(function(orderId){
       if (!orderId)
          return false;
    });

    var isValidAddressPromise = $resource("/checkAddress").then(function(orderId){
       if (!isValidAddress)
         return false;
    });

    // some other checking 

    return $q.all([orderPromise, isValidAddressPromise]).then(function(value){
        var result = value[0] || value[1]; //depends on situation change your condition
        if(result) return result;
        return $q.reject(result);
    })
};
```

Comment: Glad to know that, do click up arrow Thanks;)